# Chamar uma class pelo valor de um membro

Tags: c++

Gostaria de saber como eu poderia verificar se o id de uma classe herdada é igual a um valor x.

Algo do tipo:

```
class X {
    id = 3;
};  ...

class Y {
    id = 4;
};
```

Eu tenho uma váriavel qualquer x, como poderia verificar se x é igual ao valor id de alguma classe e chamar essa instância.

Comment: Acho que falta mais que uma lógica para criação da instância. Se suas classes não possuem relação de herança, como pretende usá-las depois? Mesmo com alguma lógica para criar as instâncias, se não há herança entre elas, você não vai poder acessar depois...

Comment: Talvez o código deva ser `class X : A`, `class Y : A`... ou então `class Y : X`.

Answer (score 0):

O código a seguir vai ilustrar bem como é que funciona isso, pelo que eu entendi isso é o que você precisa para entender o processo...

```
#include <iostream>

class foo{
    protected:
        int id;
    public:
        foo() : id(9) {}
        virtual void printId(){ printf("%d\n",id); }

};

class oof : public foo{
    public:
        oof(){
            id = 8;
        }
};

class ofo : public foo{
    public:
        ofo() : foo(){}
        void  printId(){std::cout<<id<<"\tOFO"<<std::endl;}
};

class mofu : public ofo{
    public:
        mofu(){
            id = 420;
        }
};

int main(){
    foo * a = new foo();
    foo * b = new oof();
    foo * c = new ofo();
    foo * d = new mofu();
    b->printId();
    a->printId();
    c->printId();
    d->printId();
 return 0;   
}
```

Depois que ler ele e executar, você entenderá melhor como funciona o processo.

Para fazer o que você quer, você precisaria de alguma estrutura{array, vector, list, stack...} com todas as instancias que herdam essa classe e depois de ter essas instancias é só iterar sobre a estrutura até achar as que voce quer. algo mais ou menos assim:

```
class foo{
    protected:
        int id;
    public:
        foo() : id(9) {}
        virtual void printId(){ printf("%d\n",id); }
        virtual int getId(){ return id; }
};

...
//função que pega um foo * objects[], o tamanho desse array, e um numero para a seleção, e sempre que achar a instancia de 'foo' ele chama o printId();

void selectAndExec(foo ** objects, int arrayLength, int baseArg = 9){
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayLenth; i++){
            if(objects[i]->getId() == baseArg) objects[i]->printId();
    }
}
```

O argumento default é opcional, ele é apenas uma base para poder chamar a função sem passar um id, e ele seria 9.

Esta uma das formas de se fazer isso, se pensar um pouco mais em cima desse problema é bem facil achar soluções melhores por que depende muito do que você quer com o software.